# Null Value causes Realm Crashed

Tags: ios, null, realm, nsnull

I am using Realm 0.92.3 but it crashed when I have null value despite I have set the default properties. Is there any solution on this? If not I might convert using coredata as this is very important to me. The null will be random on several properties

```
@interface WatchlistNews : RLMObject
@property NSString              *nid;
@property NSString              *tid;
@property NSString              *country;

@end


 @implementation WatchlistNews
 + (NSString *)primaryKey {
     return @"nid";
 }

 + (NSDictionary *)defaultPropertyValues {
     return @{@"nid" : @"", @"tid": @"", @"country": @""};
 }
 @end
```

Data response:

```
nid = 509319;
tid = <null>;
country = my;
```

Error code:

```
 -[NSNull UTF8String]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10712b4c0 
 Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSNull UTF8String]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10712b4c0'
```

Comment: Please post the stacktrace.  It's not obvious from the code you posted where the issue is.

Comment: @trojanfoe not sure what you meant by stacktrace but I have updated my questions with more details

Comment: OK so an `NSNull` object is being used in place of an `NSString` object.  Your code shows no use of `NSNull` objects.  You need to be checking what objects are before working on them.

Answer (score 0):

Realm do not support complex data types, so if you try to assign a complex value such as `<null>`, it gets crashed.

You should check the response you are getting from the server for the `<null>` values. And if it exists in the response replace it with an empty string. Try following code on the response you are getting, to remove the occurance of `<null>` values.

```
-(NSMutableDictionary *) removeNullFromDictionary:(NSDictionary *) originalDictionary{

NSArray *allKeysArray = [originalDictionary allKeys];
const NSMutableDictionary *replaced = [originalDictionary mutableCopy];
const id nul = [NSNull null];
const NSString *blank = @"";

for(NSString *key in allKeysArray) {

    const id object = [originalDictionary objectForKey:key];

    if(object == nul) {

        [replaced setObject:blank forKey:key];

    }
}
return [replaced copy];
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Realm does not yet support setting `nil` for `NSString` properties, but you can track progress on that by following https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/628.